# babel-loader is ignored by webpack config

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-preset-env

I'm having some issues with babel-loader and cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. It does not seem like babel-loader is transpiling at all and I have a suspicion that the babel-loader is not even being used. The result is the same even if i remove everything in the `use:` block. Adding the `debug: true` flag to options does not change the output in the console. However, the exclude/include options does work, so I am sure that the config is being used. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

```
    var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './project/src/rovbasekart.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'rovbase.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './project/src/dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/, 
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '/project/src/')],
            exclude: [/node_modules/, './project/src/dist', './project/src/lib'], // ignore all files in the node_modules folder
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { "targets": { "browsers": "ie 11"}}]],
                    babelrc: false
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-module-source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
            Rovbase: path.resolve('./project/src/'),
            Verktoylinje: path.resolve('./project/src/verktoylinje'),
            Verktoy: path.resolve('./project/src/verktoylinje/Verktoy'),
            Styles: path.resolve('./project/src/styles')
        }
    }   
};
```

Package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "ol": "^5.1.3",
    "proj4": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had both an entry-file and an include-filed. Removing the include-line solved the issue.